# Ivy- my indoor Ivy is dying from the roots- I think it could be root rot

Tags: indoors, rot, english-ivy

My indoor ivy plant grew pretty big, then my mum decided to shorten it by quite a bit and it started dying…

we put it into more sun but it kept dying. We only have one half-dead stem left! It’s dying from the roots up- I think it must be root rot. And I know we sound stupid but my mum did most of that and I know I should’ve noticed how severe it was earlier but uh I didn’t.

Should we propagate it? Is it beyond saving? This plant is very important to me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you post a picture as we cant see it